# Regex for input seperated by space to be used in php's preg_match

Tags: php, regex

I want to make sure users only put things like:

```
keyword keyword keyword
```

in my input form.

Whats the correct regex for this? I tried:

```
([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\s)+
```

However, this also matches part of this:

```
this, is a keyword
```

I want to use the regex in php's preg_match to make sure that users only enter words separated by spaces. I want to make sure there are no commas, semicolons, colons, question marks etc.
The words may contain letters (lowercase, uppercase), numbers and the dash -.

Thanks for help and tips!

Comment: Add `^` and `$` to the beginning and end of the regex, to make sure the *whole* string needs  to match, not only a part. `^([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\s)+$`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
^([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+(?:\s|$))+$
```

Use `anchors` `^$` to disallow partial matches.

https://www.regex101.com/r/fJ6cR4/22

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this by using start `^` and end `$` anchors for your regex

And simplified regex for you will be:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9\s-]+$
```

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/uF4wU9/1)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I dont quite get why that works. Why the start and end anchors?

Comment: @user3629892 this is not entirely correct.It will match strings like "         " with only spaces